# Developing Modified KNN Approach

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, training, prediction

I want to divide the training set into `n` partitions further besides testing set. How can I do that?

Furthermore, I'm creating these groups in the training set. How can I calculate centroid of each partition ?

Comment: Are you trying to implement K-Means and then KNN based on its results? Or are you just looking for a clustering technique with `n` partitions?

Comment: Clustering technique with n partitions .

Answer (score 0):

If you already know `n`, you can use `cluster` module on `scikit-learn`. Here's a toy example:

```py
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

centers = 3 #here your n should go
# Make simulated feature matrix
features, _ = make_blobs(n_samples = 50,
                             n_features = 2,
                             centers = centers,
                             random_state = 22)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(features, columns=["feature_1", "feature_2"]) 

# Make k-means clusterer
clusterer = KMeans(3, random_state=0) 
clusterer.fit(features)
```

After fitting the model, ou can get the class labels by `predict` attribute:

```
clusterer.predict(features)
```

And each observation centroid is accessible through `cluster_centers_`:

```
clusterer.cluster_centers_
```

You can use scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) on this for more information.